# Render only html from my angular4 component

Tags: html, angular, angular6, angular-components

Right now I have following HTML component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: '<div class="col-md-6">data</div><div class="col-md-6">data</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class NSOmultiselectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

}
```

If I add app-component in my code so I want to render only HTML content from this component

Current Code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">data</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">data</div>
    <app-component></app-component>
</div>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">data</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">data</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">data</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">data</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to render the only HTML from component

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert HTML to HTML entities. Please use this code in template.

```
&lt;div&gt; class="col-md-6">data&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div&gt;div class="col-md-6">data &lt;/p&gt;
```